# ADFS Error - MSIS9605: The client is not allowed to access the requested resource

Tags: node.js, adfs, microsoft-dynamics-crm, crm

I have an on-premise installation of Dynamics CRM 2016 which has claims-based authentication configured using an ADFS 4.0 (Server 2016) instance. Logging into CRM works fine via ADFS. I have a separate Node.js application trying to access the CRM Web API using the ADAL library provided by Microsoft to perform authentication. I have created an ADFS client using PowerShell for this Node app that has a Client ID and Secret. When the Node code executes to acquire a token from ADFS to use for calling the CRM Web API, I get the error *MSIS9605: The client is not allowed to access the requested resource*. Clearly the call is reaching ADFS, but I cannot seem to find a way to configure ADFS to allow the client to access the other resource protected by ADFS.

Here is the output of *Get-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust*:

```
AllowedAuthenticationClassReferences : {}
EncryptionCertificateRevocationCheck : CheckChainExcludeRoot
PublishedThroughProxy                : False
SigningCertificateRevocationCheck    : CheckChainExcludeRoot
WSFedEndpoint                        : https://crm.mysite.com/
AdditionalWSFedEndpoint              : {}
ClaimsProviderName                   : {}
ClaimsAccepted                       : {, , }
EncryptClaims                        : True
Enabled                              : True
EncryptionCertificate                : [Subject]
                                         CN=*.mysite.com, OU=Domain Control Validated

                                       [Issuer]
                                         CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2, 
                                       OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, 
                                       S=Arizona, C=US

                                       [Serial Number]
                                         2DC..............91

                                       [Not Before]
                                         11/23/2016 9:41:00 PM

                                       [Not After]
                                         1/19/2018 3:51:41 PM

                                       [Thumbprint]
                                         2FC..................AADD

Identifier                           : {https://demo.mysite.com/, https://crm.mysite.com/}
NotBeforeSkew                        : 0
EnableJWT                            : True
AlwaysRequireAuthentication          : False
Notes                                : 
OrganizationInfo                     : 
ObjectIdentifier                     : 8e869c1e-..........8b5a
ProxyEndpointMappings                : {}
ProxyTrustedEndpoints                : {}
ProtocolProfile                      : WsFed-SAML
RequestSigningCertificate            : {}
EncryptedNameIdRequired              : False
SignedSamlRequestsRequired           : False
SamlEndpoints                        : {}
SamlResponseSignature                : AssertionOnly
SignatureAlgorithm                   : http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256
TokenLifetime                        : 0
AllowedClientTypes                   : Public, Confidential
IssueOAuthRefreshTokensTo            : AllDevices
RefreshTokenProtectionEnabled        : True
RequestMFAFromClaimsProviders        : False
ScopeGroupId                         : 
Name                                 : crm.mysite.com
AutoUpdateEnabled                    : True
MonitoringEnabled                    : True
MetadataUrl                          : https://crm.mysite.com/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml
ConflictWithPublishedPolicy          : False
IssuanceAuthorizationRules           : 
IssuanceTransformRules               : @RuleTemplate = "PassThroughClaims"
                                       @RuleName = "Pass Through UPN"
                                       c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn"]
                                        => issue(claim = c);

                                       @RuleTemplate = "PassThroughClaims"
                                       @RuleName = "Pass Through Primary SID"
                                       c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/primarysid"]
                                        => issue(claim = c);

                                       @RuleTemplate = "MapClaims"
                                       @RuleName = "Transform Windows Account Name to Name"
                                       c:[Type == 
                                       "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname"]
                                        => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", 
                                       Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, 
                                       ValueType = c.ValueType);

                                       @RuleTemplate = "PassThroughClaims"
                                       @RuleName = "App Claim"
                                       c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/x-ms-clie
                                       nt-application"]
                                        => issue(claim = c);


DelegationAuthorizationRules         : 
LastPublishedPolicyCheckSuccessful   : True
LastUpdateTime                       : 1/4/2017 8:24:16 PM
LastMonitoredTime                    : 1/5/2017 8:02:07 PM
ImpersonationAuthorizationRules      : 
AdditionalAuthenticationRules        : 
AccessControlPolicyName              : Permit everyone
AccessControlPolicyParameters        : 
ResultantPolicy                      : RequireFreshAuthentication:False
                                       IssuanceAuthorizationRules:
                                       {
                                         Permit everyone
                                       }
```

Here is the Node.js function using ADAL (https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs). I realize it has Azure in the title but it is successfully communicating with ADFS and there are comments in the issues log stating that what I am doing is possible.

```
let ADAuthenticationContext = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;

const authorityHostUrl = 'https://sso.mysite.com';
const tenant = 'adfs';
let authorityUrl = authorityHostUrl + '/' + tenant;
const clientId = 'c43002e2-............67c';
const clientSecret = 'lT..................jjh';

const resource = 'https://crm.mysite.com/';


let crm = module.exports = {};

let context = new ADAuthenticationContext(authorityUrl, false);

crm.test = function() {
    context.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(resource, clientId, clientSecret, function(err, tokenResponse) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('well that didn\'t work: ' + err.stack);
        } else {
            console.log(tokenResponse);
        }
    });
};
```

Also, from the ADFS Event Log:

```
Encountered error during OAuth token request. 

Additional Data 

Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.Exceptions.OAuthUnauthorizedClientException: MSIS9321: Received invalid OAuth request. The client 'c43002e2-f1a6-4786-9234-f71e971c167c' is forbidden to access the resource 'https://demo.mysite.com/'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.OAuthProtocolContext.ValidateScopes(String scopeParameter, String clientId, String relyingPartyId)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.OAuthToken.OAuthClientCredentialsContext.ValidateCore()
```

Any insight would be great as I am pretty new to ADFS and the message seems to indicate something in ADFS is not correct.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows Server 2016 you need to explicitly grant clients permission to a resource, even when the access policy is set to "Permit everyone".

Try this command:

```
Grant-AdfsApplicationPermission -ClientRoleIdentifier "clientName" -ServerRoleIdentifier "https://service.url"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a rule to permit or deny users based on an incoming claim.

In Windows Server 2016, you can use an Access Control Policy to create a rule that will permit or deny users based on an incoming claim. Also, you can permit all users to access the relying party, use the **Permit Everyone** Access Control Policy or the **Permit All Users** rule template

You can refer to the article below for creating the rule by using the AD FS Management.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-fs/operations/create-a-rule-to-permit-or-deny-users-based-on-an-incoming-claim?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Or you also can use the following command with related parameters running in PowerShell.

```
Add-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -Name "Fabrikam" -MetadataURL "https://fabrikam.com/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml" -IssuanceAuthorizationRules '=> issue(Type ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/authorization/claims/permit", value="true");'
```

Comment: The existing relying party trust already was already using the Permit Everyone rule template. Do I need to create another relying party trust for the Node app?

Comment: I recommend to create relying party trust by using command in PowerShell, and please make sure add the following in the command.  -IssuanceAuthorizationRules '=> issue(Type ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/authorization/claims/permit", value="true");'

Comment: I deleted the relying party trust and recreated it using PowerShell following your template. No change, error still persists.

Comment: How did you register the Node App with ADFS by using PowerShell? Did you set the client type as **Public** or **Confidential**? You may refer to the article [AD FS Scenarios for Developers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-scenarios-for-developers?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for the scenarios in Windows Server 2016.

Comment: ive the exact same problem. Ive got ADFS+OAuth2 setup scenario. I cant get the `code` from authorisation step. I keep getting `MSIS9605` as a response. and on the adfs server logs, I can only see error 1020 and 364

Comment: BTW, in answer to Andy's question it was set to public. Via a support call with Microsoft they told me CRM with ADFS 4.0 is unsupported as of this date.